# Why can't I access Ubuntu without my Flash Drive?

Tags: boot, usb-installation

1. I installed Ubuntu through my USB drive/ Flash drive.
2. When the installation was complete, it tells me to restart my computer, so I did.
3. I restarted my computer while the flash drive is still plugged in. I was then directed to the same page where the options: try ubunti without installation, install ubuntu, and etc were listed.
4. When I removed my flashdrive, it brought me to the boot menu.

Can you help me fix this problem? Thank you so much.

Update:
Boot Menu [boot menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPKeu.jpg)

Comment: When restart after installation, it tells you to unplug the flash drive. Try that as a fix.

Comment: I removed the flash drive before clicking 'restart now'. There was no option telling me to unplug my flashdrive. Anyway, I'm reinstalling it, click restart now, and remove flashdrive before it restarts.

Comment: Can you post the content of the boot menu?

Comment: Added a photo to the original post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 10 with UEFI](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi)

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the boot priority in the bios menu. 
You are still using the USB drive as the default device in the boot.
Restart your system, get the boot menu and select the hard disk as your device to boot from.

Comment: I tried to change the boot priority earlier, but there was only one boot option and that is the USB drive.

Comment: Can you please check this link. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2122159

Comment: I am not a techie from what I've understand I'll have to delete 'UEFI: General UDisk 5.00' for the hard drive to boot, correct?

Comment: Now Im stuck at please remove the installation medium, then press enter. But it isn't hanging the dots below the ubunto logo is moving